# Estimating Gamma MLE with left truncated data (using R and maxLik)

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, optimization, gamma-distribution, truncation

I'm trying to find the maximum likelihood estimation of the parameters of a Gamma distributed random variable using `maxLik`.

The following code explain what I did:

```
library(maxLik)
library(pracma) # Used for calculating incomplete Gamma (with gammainc)

## Likelihood function I want to maximize

LL <- function(param){
  k     <- param[1]
  theta <- param[2]
  (k-1)*sum(log(x)) - (sum(x)/theta)-k*log(theta) - sum(gammainc(d,k))
}

## Starting parameters -- estimated with the method of moment 
## respectively k and theta
param = c(0.05264, 2191.93)


## data
x = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,2300,0,0,0,0,0,0,2200,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

## truncation points 
d = c(1000, 500, 500, 500, 500 ,500 ,500, 1000, 1000, 500, 500, 500, 500 
      1000, 500, 500, 500, 500 ,500 ,500, 1000, 500, 500)

## maxLik
res <- maxLik(LL, start=c(0.05264, 2191.93))
```

How can I find the MLE for the parameters of my function?

PS: In the documentation, examples for `maxLik` don't explicitly call the arguments in the likelihood function, how can `maxLik` even know what x and d (in my case) are?

Comment: Welcome to our site! Have a look at our [help/on-topic] to get a feel for the kind of issues that are considered on-topic here. A lot of this question seems to revolve around debugging code, which is explicitly outside the scope of this site, but it seems you might have a genuinely *statistical* (rather than coding) issue here too. Do you think you could edit your question to refocus it on the statistical aspect and de-emphasise the debugging?

Comment: @Silverfish Edited!

Comment: There may be enough statistical content here for this to be on topic.

Comment: Thanks for your edits. I agree with @gung that the statistical aspect here is likely on-topic.

Comment: It seems that the 'PS' question is about the scope of variables `x` and `d`
in R. Searching about *lexical scoping* could help you.  Note that the
`pgamma` function has args `lower.tail` and `log.p` which will give
the required incomplete gamma. Using the classical `optim` function
might also be an option here. Finally, the elements of `x` do not seem 
compatible with your model as I understand it.